# Featured Image URL is Showing but not thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

I added posts from other CMS to my new word press site. For featured images I changed, `wp_post` table as

```
post ID: 2300
```

**Attachment in "wp_post":**

```
ID:3400
post_type: attachment
post_mime_type: images/jpeg
post_parent: 2300
post_title: file name
post_name: fileName-in-WP-Content-upload
post_status:inherit
guid: site.com/upload/oldImages/fileName-in-WP-Content-upload.jpg
```

**Making Featured image in "wp_postmeta"**

```
post_id:2300
meta_key: _thmubnail_id
meta_value: 3400
```

Now I am not seeing featured image in post however I can see the image url with

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(3400) );
```

Comment: How are you (or theme) calling featured image in post? What output exactly are you getting?

Comment: @Rarst I have my default theme, when I add feature image via admin panel it shows in feature image section when we edit post from admin panel, But as I have made the image featured from database & uploaded manually via ftp client it is not displaying in the featured image section, but yes I can get its url

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display the post thumbnail for the attachment itself:

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( 3400 ) )
```

Instead, use:

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( 2300 ) )
```

Comment: No that was not my question, What I am asking is, in default we see an image in admin panel while editing a post in the featured image section, but as I have added the image by database & uploaded it via ftp client, this image is not showing in the featured image section but yes I can get the image's url with get_post_thumbnail_id()

Comment: It's all in the ID - you're trying to get the featured image of the featured image! Use the ID of the post you're setting the featured image *for*.

Comment: No, I mistyped here about ID,  I am asking here is, I cannot see this custome made featured image in admin panel however if I upload an image from admin panel I see it there